# Difference between BOUND and CONNECTED channel states in Netty

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I am trying to understand the difference between `BOUND` and `CONNECTED` [channel states](https://netty.io/3.10/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelState.html) provided by Netty.

When does [`channelBound()`](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.html#channelBound(org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent)) gets called and when [`channelConnected()`](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.html#channelConnected(org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent)) gets called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding precedes connecting. Binding is the step where an IP address and port are associated with the socket. It is typically only an explicit step for a listening socket. Connection takes place when a socket is either connected to a server or accepted from a client. In the latter case the bind and connect steps are usually combined, or rather the bind is done implicitly by the connect call.

Comment: @informatik01 Edit rejected. I am not in need of your typographical assistance. I never use bold-face.

Comment: Wow, sorry if I somehow hurt your aesthetical feelings :-) First time in 10 years I see such reaction. People are getting too sensitive nowadays...